# ant (1.8.0/1.8.1) zip empty directories

Tags: ant

I noticed that neither the zip or jar targets are including empty directories.  I googled a little and found this was a regression issue way back with 1.6 (.2 I think), but it was claimed to have been fixed.  I was using 1.8.0 so I upgraded to 1.8.1, but am having the same issue.  Anyone know of any workarounds besides adding dummy files to those directories?
Thanks,
Ben Anderson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with my version apache-ant-1.8.0RC1

Are you opening the file using WinZip? 
In WinZip you dont see the empty dirs, but try extracting with WinZip and you will see even the empty dirs are created.

Comment: yep - that was it.  Thanks!  Geez - never considered winzip would hide the folder.